GKE Ingress not accepting "Certificates" but only "Classic Certificates"
How do i map a certificate in GCP Managed Certificates "Certificates" to a LB through GKE Ingress yaml?
I have a 3rd party that is provisioning certificates to the "Certificates" section of "Certificate Manager" via API. When I created my GKE Ingress through UI a certificate in the "Certificates" section is never shown but all in "Classic Certificates" are shown.
If i attempt to write a Ingress with networking.gke.io/managed-certificates: mycertificate GCP will always create a certificate with "Classic Certificates".
I was able to map the certificate provided into "Certificates" to a test nginx cloud run instance through many gcloud commands. But i have not been successful in mapping this to a L7 LB through GKE ingress.
